# How to add a scrollbar to a Text in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a code in which you type a question and it fetches an answer from Wikipedia once you press the 'Search' button. However decent I may be at python and tkinter, I'm stuck on this. I know how to add a scrollbar, set it, set it's command, set the y/xscrollcommand and pack it but it's not working and I could use some help.
Thanks in advance for any help I get.

```
#-----Import library-----#
import wikipedia
from tkinter import *

#-----Create window-----#
window=Tk()
iconpic=PhotoImage(file='Cat.png')
window.iconphoto(False, iconpic)
window.title('ChatCat')
window.geometry('400x517')
window.config(bg='#242121')
window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

#-----Define functions-----#
def two_sentence():
    global number_o_sentences
    number_o_sentences=2
def three_sentence():
    global number_o_sentences
    number_o_sentences=3
def four_sentence():
    global number_o_sentences
    number_o_sentences=4
def five_sentence():
    global number_o_sentences
    number_o_sentences=5
def reply():
    Label(chatWindow, text=(messageWindow.get('1.0', 'end-1c')), wraplength='250', justify='right', fg='#502ec9', bg='#242121').pack(side='top', anchor='e', pady=3)
    Label(chatWindow, text=(wikipedia.summary(messageWindow.get('1.0', 'end-1c'), sentences=number_o_sentences)), wraplength='350', justify='left', fg='#b02832', bg='#242121').pack(side='top', anchor='w', pady=3)

#-----Create menu-----#
main_menu=Menu(window)
main_menu.add_command(label="Two", command=two_sentence)
main_menu.add_command(label="Three", command=three_sentence)
main_menu.add_command(label="Four", command=four_sentence)
main_menu.add_command(label="Five", command=five_sentence)
main_menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=window.quit)
window.config(menu=main_menu)

#-----Create conversation window-----#
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window, cursor="target")
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill='y')
chatWindow = Text(window, bd=1, bg="black",  width="50", height="8", font=("Arial", 23), foreground="#00ffff", yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
chatWindow.place(x=6,y=6, height=385, width=370)
messageWindow = Text(window, bd=0, bg="black",width="30", height="4", font=("Arial", 23), foreground="#00ffff", highlightcolor='white', borderwidth=2)
messageWindow.place(x=128, y=400, height=88, width=247)
scrollbar.config(command=chatWindow.yview)
button=Button(window, text="Search",  width="12", height=5, bd=0, bg="#2d3652", activebackground="#00bfff",foreground='#ffffff',font=("Arial", 12), command=reply)
button.place(x=6, y=400, height=88)
Label(chatWindow, text='Select the number of sentences you want above and start searching', wraplength='350', justify='left', fg='#b02832', bg='#242121').pack(side='top', anchor='w', pady=3)

#-----Run window-----#
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you can have one function and pass it different arguments, you don't need 5 functions that effectively only differ by one digit, it may be a bit confusing but in this case you would do it sth like this: `command=lambda: num_of_sentences(2)`

Comment: I suggest you use a [`tkinter.scrolledtext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html#module-tkinter.scrolledtext) widget.

Comment: You should use `chatWindow.insert(...)` instead of packing label widgets into it.

Comment: what do you mean by _it is not working_? if I add enough text to the widget (the one where to type the search stuff I guess), I can easily use the scrollbar to scroll it

Comment: How do you know it's not working? I don't see anywhere that inserts text into the window. There's nothing to scroll. When I type multiple lines into the text widget, the scrollbar works.

Comment: 1: I want to keep it that way so its easy to understand in the future.   
2: I'll look into it.   
3: It gives it a nice look than everything looking the same and text being too big.                                                                                                           

I get your point, is there a way I can scroll through the labels?

Comment: There are multiple examples on [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrollable+frame+tkinter) and elsewhere on how to create a "scrollable" frame. Also those functions are not gonna help you understand much more in the future, just use one function, give it a reasonable, self-explanatory name and add a docstring (which really is of help in the future, much more than having 5 functions doing basically the same thing)

Comment: Wait what I make the chatwindow anything but a Text like a canvas or anything that would be properly scrollable?

Comment: In the future, I highly recommend that you provide a [example]. Since some may not have the `wikipedia` module installed, or don't happen to have a `Cat.png` in the right directory, this code takes a decent amount of work to test. Ideally, question code should be able to be copy-paste-run. Also, a lot of this code (like the `wikipedia` module and `Cat.png`) aren't really necessary for demonstrating your problem. See the [help] for more information.

Comment: I see your point Sylvester, I'll do that with my next question